# How to add date to empty cell by default if none specified in Google Form, on form submit with App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a time log form that has a date field I do not want to have to fill out every time as 90% of the time the date would be today's date.  (Sometimes you will be entering something from another day and need to change it).

When an entry is added column A is always going to have something, so it should check to see if A is empty and if that same rows D is empty it will input today's date into D.

Some of the example's I have looked at were for onEdit of cell change it, but I could not get it to work with a form submit or even just have it automatically check all the cells in D and if empty put today's date (Only when B has value).

I have a function to sort the sheet right now that is called when on form submit/onEdit happens and would like to stick the new formula in the bottom of the same one (unless that is bad practice).  The reason for this is less functions to have to add to the trigger list.

A: Timestamp | B: What | C: Paid? | D: Date

Comment: Hi Davey, could you please add some code snippet relate to your description?

Comment: Hey, I didn't post any related code as everything I had semi working felt wrong and did not want to confuse people.  After work today I will try again and post some code.  The basis of the function would be to have a function called from the Triggers onEdit, onFormSubmit (Just onFormSubmit might work now that I think about it) - is the cell in column D Empty && this rows cell in column A !empty? Then put todays date in column D's cell.  As you can tell I can describe it, but still unable to write my own custom functions.  Hopefully soon this will change

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Date` from [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=1361471) which Google Sheets offers.

And, as mentioned in [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), if the available functions aren't enough for your needs, you can also use Google Apps Script to write custom functions then use them in Google Sheets just like a built-in function.

To get started, guidelines for custom functions and samples can be found in the given documentations.

Comment: The issue with using functions/custom is once a form response is submitted it basically creates a new line without any of the formatting from the Google Sheet.  I have found adding functions to a column doesn't apply to new entries and it requires App Script to edit any of the newly added form lines (I may be completely wrong on this, but is the conclusion I came to after many hours of frustration when first using Sheets/forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Apps Script with `onFormSubmit` trigger which will populate the said cell with default date.

Here is a sample code which will populate the current date in Column 4 of the row in question.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //edit responses sheet name
  var responseSheetName = 'Form Responses 2';
  //Edit colmn number, column in which the date has to be autopopulated
  var column = 4;

  //Get target row number
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  //If no date, pouplate the cell with current date
  if(!e.values[column-1]){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(responseSheetName).getRange(row, column).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

In order to setup the above code, open the Spreadsheet which contains the form responses. Go Tools > Script Editor. This will open script editor window. Paste above code and edit the `responseSheetName` and `column` . Now Save it.
 After saving it, setup an on form submit trigger.

To setup the trigger, follow these steps.

1. From the script editor, choose Resources > Current project's triggers.
2. Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
3. Under Run, select the name of function *onFormSubmit* which you want to trigger.
4. Under Events, select *From spreadsheet*.
5. Select *On form submit*
6. Optionally, click Notifications to configure how and when you will be contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
7. Click Save.

Comment: This is so close, is there a way to target the last added row or just all rows that are empty?  I have another function which sorts everything based on multiple columns so the new entry is never the first or last items.

Comment: I also have 2 columns with data validation dropdowns that are on every row to the bottom causing the last line to be at 1000+ (there is probably a better way to do that though)

Comment: I'll recommend not to edit/sort/add dropdown in form submission sheet. Once the data is submitted, you just take a copy of the data in another sheet and do whatever you need to, otherwise, you form submission may behave in unexpected way.

Comment: The issue I would have with that is that I need to edit the submitted data as soon as the data is submitted.

Example:
I use this as a daytime log.
After entering the date, time, description of what i did, I don't always enter the end time.  So after submitting and complete the task I have a shortcut on my phone I open up and then have the newest date entries at the top (I used to scroll down and this became unbearable on mobile). Here is a link to a example form/responses https://drive.google.com/open?id=14zKZ8fsNOnOtKobLom43cSyO_bK_fRqem8Sih9sEZzM

Comment: In this case, I'll recommend to use custom built form using Apps Script HtmlService. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry to take you down this rabbit hole.  Much appreciated